# Jittering the lines in ggplot produces two symbols for one data point

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a simple line plot and jitter the lines.

```
library(ggplot2)
test=read.table(text= "
  group  x  y
  1 1   17  
  1 2   16  
  2 1   13
  2 2   12.5
  ", header=TRUE, sep=""  )        

pd <- position_dodge(.2)

qplot(x=x, y=y, data=test, group=group, colour=group ) +
geom_line(position=pd )+
geom_point(position=pd, size=6)
```

I am getting

```
ymax not defined: adjusting position using y instead
ymax not defined: adjusting position using y instead
```

warnings and somehow two symbols are displayed for each data point instead of one:
[image]

I assume the ymax warning has something to do with getting two symbols. I'd appreciate any help. thanks!

Comment: Simply Googling the warning message [suggests](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ggplot2/PGzx4u6U84Y) that it was a debugging message (not even a warning) that perhaps should have been removed in the case of dodge but has not yet.

Comment: This is what I found as well, however, I am getting two symbols where I would expect just one. Somehow the jittering does not work.

Comment: That's because you're using `qplot`, which is only really advisable for the very simplest situations. (`qplot` automatically guesses and _applies_ a `geom`, in this case, probably `geom_point`. Hence the duplication of the points.)

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not even realize the difference. The following code works:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
test=read.table(text= "
  group  x  y
  1 1   17  
  1 2   16  
  2 1   13
  2 2   12.5
  ", header=TRUE, sep=""  )        

ggplot(data=test, aes(x=x, y=y, group=group, colour=group)) + 
  geom_line(position=position_dodge(0.2))+
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(0.2))
```

[image]